# Can't connect my database on my live server

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I've been making a site on my local server and I finished it so I'm moving everything over to my live server. I've made a database in phpmyadmin on it and I would like to connect to it. I feel like I have the wrong inputs though because it gives me this error.

[image]

This is my code for my database connection.

```
<?php

return $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'gener105_nate', '(Password)', 'user_data');

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error);
}
```

I didn't actually enter password I just think I shouldn't show it anyway I think I just have something mixed up since I'm new at this.

Oh and the database is located within a database grouping should i input the path to it?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post text in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it to connect to gener105_user_data instead of just user_data

```
return $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'gener105_nate', '(Password)', 'gener105_user_data');
```

Comment: I'm dumb I forgot I renamed it XD

Comment: It happens to all of us. Please mark the question as solved. Thanks.

Comment: I am I gotta wait a minute though

Comment: Thanks! Also, a suggestion. Learn PDO instead of using mysqli, it's better in the long run.

Comment: I haven't even heard of that! Thanks dude I'm gunna give a try after I get payed for this project